# Chrome is opening but not performing the operations next

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

```js
const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");

const builder = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome");

const chromeOptions = new chrome.Options();
chromeOptions.setChromeBinaryPath(
  "../../../../Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
);
builder.setChromeOptions(chromeOptions);

const driverPromise = builder.build();

// Handle promise rejection
driverPromise.catch((error) => {
  console.error("Error building WebDriver:", error);
});

module.exports = driverPromise;

// In Other File
const setupDriver = require("./controllers/setUpDrive");


let driver = await setupDriver();
const user = await loginToLinkedIn(driver);


function loginToLinkedIn(driver) {
  return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
    await driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com");
    const response = await Login(driver);
    await driver.wait(until.titleContains("LinkedIn"), 5000);
    res(response);
  });
}
```

I tried but no solutions yet

With this modification, any error that occurs during the building of the WebDriver instance will be caught and logged. You can use **`driverPromise`** wherever you need to use the WebDriver instance, ensuring proper handling of asynchronous operations.